# Connect to Mysql Database from within Android App

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am developing a mobile app and trying to connect to the MySQL database using Android Studio, and this MySQL server has hosted in some IP address. I have given all the details of the server like username, password, hostname, database and table also. But, when I am trying to connect it is showing jdbc error or unable to connect to database. I have tried the MYSQL connector path from android studio **"implementation("mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.33")"** also tried to give a connector from **implementation(files("C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\id3\app\libs\mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar"))**. But after this also it is not able to connect, it is showing the same error.

This is my Database_Connection code.

```
package com.example.id3;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class DatabaseConnection {

    private static final String IP = "137.325.197.0"; // IP address of the MySQL server
    private static final String PORT = "3306"; // Port number of the MySQL server
    private static final String USERNAME = "root"; // Username for database access
    private static final String PASSWORD = "35689@it"; // Password for database access
    private static final String DB_NAME = "connection"; // Name of the database

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(DatabaseConnection.class.getName());

    // Establishes a connection to the MySQL database
    public static Connection establishConnection() {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            // Registering the MySQL JDBC driver
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

            // Creating the JDBC URL
            String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://" + IP + ":" + PORT + "/" + DB_NAME;

            // Attempting to establish the connection
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            // Log error message
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error establishing connection to the database", e);
        }
        return connection;
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.id3;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class connsql {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(connsql.class.getName());

    // Validates user credentials by querying the database
    public static boolean validateCredentials(String user_id, String password) {
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement statement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;

        try {
            // Establishing a database connection
            connection = DatabaseConnection.establishConnection();

            if (connection != null) {
                // Preparing the SQL query
                String query = "SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE user_id = ? AND password = ?";
                statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);

                // Binding parameters
                statement.setString(1, user_id);
                statement.setString(2, password);

                // Executing the query
                resultSet = statement.executeQuery();

                // Checking if result set has any data
                return resultSet.next(); // If there's a match, resultSet will have at least one row
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error validating credentials", e);
        } finally {
            // Closing resources in a finally block to ensure they are always closed
            try {
                if (resultSet != null) {
                    resultSet.close();
                }
                if (statement != null) {
                    statement.close();
                }
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error closing resources", e);
            }
        }
        return false; // Credentials are invalid or database connection failed
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the full error message and stack trace in your question. The error is not in Android Studio but in your Android app. Android Studio is just the IDE you use for building the app. Once it runs all errors don't have anything to do with AS, just with the code you have written and the libraries you use.